# How do i rotate an image in pygame while maintaining its position?

Tags: python-3.x, rotation, pygame

I'm trying to rotate an image while maintaining its center position. I've tried following instructions from another question asked but it doesn't seem to have the exact same problem which I'm facing.

when i rotate the image, it rotates from its center but the center position seems to change and it appears as if my image bounces up and down while being rotated.

here is the code:

```
import pygame
import sys
import math

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

img_load = pygame.image.load("img/test.png")
img = pygame.transform.scale(img_load,(40,40))
bg = pygame.image.load("img/bgblack.png")

img_x = 300
img_y = 300

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    m_x,m_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    radians = math.atan2(m_y - img_y, m_x - img_x)
    degrees = math.degrees(radians)

    img_center = img.get_rect().center
    rot_img = pygame.transform.rotate(img,-degrees) 
    rot_img.get_rect().center = img_center

    screen.blit(bg,(0,0))
    screen.blit(rot_img,(img_x,img_y))

    pygame.display.update()
```

your help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I have not used pygame, but typically what you do in game engines like this is first translate your sprite to where its center axis would be, then apply the rotation, then translate back to where you want it to appear on-screen.

So for example, if you wanted to rotate around the center of the sprite, first you'd move it by half its width and height, so that its center is at world (0,0). Then apply rotation, and translate into position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `rect = rot_img.get_rect(center=(img_x, img_y))` and you'll get a rect that you can use as the blit position. The `center=(img_x, img_y)` argument sets the center of the rect to the desired coordinates.

```
m_x,m_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

radians = math.atan2(m_y - img_y, m_x - img_x)
degrees = math.degrees(radians)

rot_img = pygame.transform.rotate(img, -degrees) 
rect = rot_img.get_rect(center=(img_x, img_y))

screen.blit(bg,(0,0))
screen.blit(rot_img, rect)
```